# TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'document'

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I tried to bind both the comparing attribute and $set attribute in a single variable and rendered to update function in mongodb. But it give me the below error

> TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'document'

Python 3
MongoDB

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client.Mydb
collection = db.sampledb
new_contact = "6369723748"
updatestmt = "{\"ID\" : \"12345\"},{\"$set\" :{\"ID\" : \"67891\",\"Account_Number\" : \"1234 5678 9101\"}}"
print(updatestmt)

cursor = collection.update(updatestmt)
cursor1 = collection.find()

for i in cursor1:
    print(i)
```

Expected Result:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Actual Result:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "dbupdate.py", line 12, in
>
> cursor = collection.update(updatestmt)
>
> TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'document'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pymongo` is working with dictionaries, not strings. (the error just tells you you are passing one single string, while it is expecting at least two arguments).

Hence use:

```
query = {"ID" : "12345"}
new_values = {"$set" : {"ID" : "67891", "Account_Number" : "1234 5678 9101"}}

cursor = collection.update(query, new_values)
```

Or, to match your syntax:

```
updatestmt = ({"ID" : "12345"}, {"$set" : {"ID" : "67891", "Account_Number" : "1234 5678 9101"}})
cursor = collection.update(*updatestmt)
```

---

BTW: `update` is now replaced with `update_one` (for your need), or `update_many` (if the query could match multiple records)

Answer (score 2):

`update()` is [deprecated](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) and you should really use [update_one()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) instead.

```py
cursor = collection.update({'ID' : '12345'}, {'$set' : {'ID' : '67891', 'Account_Number' : '1234 5678 9101'}})
```

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for your reply, however I want to update many rows all together.

Comment: There is also [update_many()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) :) It works the same as in mongo.